# react native how to use props in method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use a method with props. I have method and I want to pass a prop inside a method. This is my method:

```
const multipleData1 = ['1 ', '2 ', '3 ', '4']
const multipleData2 = ['6 ', '7 ', '8 ', '9']
const multipleData3 = ['10 ', '11', '12 ', '13']

regionSelectHandler(){
     return(
     <View>
     {
      multipleData1.map(
         (interest) =>
           <SelectMultipleButton
             key={interest}
             buttonViewStyle={{
               borderRadius: 0,
               height: 40,
               width: 110,
             }}
             textStyle={{
               fontSize: 15,
             }}
           />
         )
      }
     </View>
   )}
```

Is there a way I could pass a prop in `multipleData1.map` so that I don't have to copy and paste the hole code each time I try to access to `const multipleData2` and `const multipleData3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
regionSelectHandler(data){
     return(
     <View>
     {
      data.map(
```

Now, when you call `regionSelectHandler` pass the array:

```
regionSelectHandler(multipleData1)
```